# How can I know if an airline has a non-expired US Customs Visa Waiver Agreement?

Tags: usa, airlines, us-visa-waiver-program

I read on https://simpleflying.com/philippine-airlines-us-visa-waiver-carrier-agreement-expires/:

> Philippine Airlines' US Customs Visa Waiver Agreement has expired, preventing them from transporting passengers to the US who rely on this program.

How can I know if an airline has a non-expired US Customs Visa Waiver Agreement?

Comment: Why would you care?

Comment: @littleadv Taking such an airline to the US under the VWP is then illegal, and you will be denied boarding (such as what is happening with [PAL](https://www.philippineairlines.com/en/newsevent-listingpage/travel-advisory/advisory-for-travelers-covered-by-us-visa-waiver-program) or detained on arrival/refused entry (this is what happens with private plane/boats)

Comment: @NicolasFormichella no, it's not illegal, and if you're denied boarding the airline would be responsible to find an alternative route for you (see examples in the article linked to in the question by the OP)

Comment: @littleadv Do you enjoy getting denied boarding? Sounds like we have different hobbies.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt a company I fly with occasionally is not in that list and that has not prevented me from flying with them. Not sure what makes you think you'd be denied boarding. This is a contract between the airline and the US government that has **absolutely nothing** to do with you. Despite the erroneous comment above, *you* are not impacted by this agreement in no way, shape or form, and if the airline *chooses* not to carry you - it's their problem to find you different arrangements and not yours.

Comment: @littleadv "you are not impacted by this agreement in no way, shape or form" https://simpleflying.com/philippine-airlines-us-visa-waiver-carrier-agreement-expires/?newsletter_popup=1 mentioned that passengers got rebooked.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt that was the choice the airline made. It also mentioned that the passengers got very generous compensation. Airlines rebook passengers for a variety of reasons. The airline didn't *have to* rebook those passengers, and they would not have been denied entry. The airline would have to pay a fine to the US government for carrying them, the choice to pay the fine or pay the compensation to rebooked passengers is up to the airline.

Comment: @littleadv - please keep it civil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at the [Signatory Visa Waiver Program carriers](https://www.cbp.gov/document/report/signatory-visa-waiver-program-vwp-carriers) list (at time of post, last updated on August 1st)

If you look at the list, Philippine Airline is not a signatory anymore and, for still signatory airline, the agreement expiry date is affixed to the name, an agreement lasting 7 years

Comment: Thanks! Follow-ups: [Why are there non-carriers in the Signatory Visa Waiver Program carriers list?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/183645/1810); [How can I search for all the texts in red in a PDF file?](https://superuser.com/q/1809185/116475). Note that for some companies one has to search for their parent companies, e.g. "Air France" isn't in the list, but their parent company KLM is.